# European crime data with spatial coordinates

Tags: data-request, geospatial, crime, europe

I am looking for prostitution arrest and drug arrest data for a couple of major cities in Western Europe. So cities such as Paris, Rome, Rotterdam, Amsterdam, Berlin, etc. Ideally the data would have dates for each arrest, as well as latitude and longitude coordinates--or atleast some street address that I can geocode. The date range would be between for at least 1 year between 2010-2015.

I looked at the police department sites for different European city police stations, but in many cases I could not read the language to navigate the site. I have found similar data for US cities, such as Boston and San Diego. But I wanted some European data to compare.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**london.gov** has a crime dataset for 2014. It breaks down crime on a per month basis/number of incidents:
http://data.london.gov.uk/dataset/recorded-crime-summary-data-london-lsoa-level

Comment: Wow, this is pretty nice for London. They have the ward and sub-ward level, which is relatively fine grained :). Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 6):

For Europe you can find historical data in this database:
http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/crime/database

not with lat lon but rather NUTS-3 regions. you can obtain coordinates for the regions using geopy

Answer (score 4):

For the UK, you can find Crime Datasets/Statistics at [data.gov.uk](http://data.gov.uk/dataset/crime_statistics) published by Office for National Statistics licensed under [Open Government Licence](http://www.nationalarchives.gov.uk/doc/open-government-licence/version/3/). Or directly at [ONS site](http://www.ons.gov.uk/ons/rel/crime-stats/crime-statistics/index.html).